# Port forwarding and SSH into Pi from external addresses

Tags: ssh, dns-hosting

I've been trying to log into my Pi (I got this around 2013, so I think it's the very first B-model) from outside my home network (I can SSH without issues from within the same LAN).

I've set up DDNS using NoIP (so I'm at myserver.ddns.net) and I believe I've set up port forwarding correctly on my router -- i.e. port 22 is sent to the local ip address of my Pi on the LAN, `192.168.x.x`

If I try to log in from outside via pi@myserver.ddns.net I'm told to enter my password `pi@myserver.ddns.net`'s password: But using the password to my Pi, my router or anything else does not work, and in the end I get `pi@myserver.ddns.net: Permission denied (publickey,password)`.

Does anyone have any experience with this, or point me in the direction of where I can figure this out? I think the problem I've had googling this is that there are a lot of more complicated issues related to this that seem more frequently queried so my rather basic problem is not really addressed as far as I can tell.

As a side note, pinging my server works, and doing `telnet myserver.ddns.net 22` leads to a connection (as far as I can tell.)
As you can tell I'm relatively inexperienced with networking but hoping to learn, so forgive my lack of technical knowledge.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/72349/how-to-run-an-ssh-server-without-a-static-ip-address

Answer (score 0):

Wonder if you are actually connecting to someone elses ssh server because the IP is not actually correct.
-v adds verbosity, -vv more verbosity, and -vvv can be a firehose.
`ssh -v pi@myserver.ddns.net` will tell you more about what is going on.
What do log files say on your Pi when attempting to do this?

Troubleshooting will even be easier if you copy your public key from the client machine into the Pi ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file.  For one, it can indicate whether you are really connecting to the machine you think you are connecting to.  It will also save time from mistyping passwords.
`ssh-copy-id pi@myserver.ddns.net`

The simplest way to troubleshoot this would be to be physically at home with your laptop connected to neighbors WiFi or a 4G cellular connection.  Open myip.dnsomatic.com on the Pi to verify that it matches the IP address from myserver.ddns.net from your laptop.

Google on how to disable password logon and use ssh keys only.